# Remove links from pdf by itextsharp .net

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I want remove all link from pdf file. i'm using code below to detect annotations:

```
static void RemoveLinks(PdfReader reader, int sourcePage)
{
    PdfDictionary sourcePageDict = reader.GetPageNRelease(sourcePage);
    PdfArray annotations = sourcePageDict.GetAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);
    if (annotations != null && annotations.Size > 0)
    {
        foreach (var item in annotations)
        {
            var annotationObject = PdfReader.GetPdfObject(item);


            if (!annotationObject.IsDictionary())
                continue;
            PdfDictionary annotation = (PdfDictionary) annotationObject;
            if (!PdfName.LINK.Equals(annotation.GetAsName(PdfName.SUBTYPE)))
                continue;

            //To do remove annotation
        }
    }
}
```

However annotationObject is not dictionary so i can't find link to remove

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You say `annotationObject` is not a dictionary. It should be.
Your screenshot shows that `annotations` is an array of indirect references, which is expected. With `GetPdfObject`, you resolve an indirect reference to a direct object, which is a dictionary in this case.

If the PDF file you're processing has an `Annots` array with indirect references that do not refer to annotation dictionaries, it's technically an invalid PDF. It would be useful if you can share it.

To remove links, you can simply remove all the link annotations:

```
static void RemoveLinks(PdfReader reader, int sourcePage, Stream output)
{
    // PdfStamper to alter the file
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, output);
    PdfDictionary sourcePageDict = reader.GetPageNRelease(sourcePage);
    PdfArray annotations = sourcePageDict.GetAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);
    // Annotations to keep
    PdfArray newannots = new PdfArray();
    if (annotations != null && annotations.Size > 0)
    {
        foreach (PdfObject item in annotations)
        {
            PdfObject annotationObject = PdfReader.GetPdfObject(item);

            if (!annotationObject.IsDictionary())
                continue;
            PdfDictionary annotation = (PdfDictionary)annotationObject;
            if (!PdfName.LINK.Equals(annotation.GetAsName(PdfName.SUBTYPE)))
                // Keep annotation when it's not a link annotation
                newannots.Add(item);
        }
        // Replace annots array for this page
        sourcePageDict.Put(PdfName.ANNOTS, newannots);
    }
    stamper.Close();
}
```